# How to check email validation?What is the error?

Tags: java, android, regex, email-validation

I tried this simple example.

```
final String email = edt.getText().toString().trim();

    //final String emailPattern = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";
    final String emailPattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z]+\\.+[a-z]+";



    btnchk.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if (email.matches(emailPattern))
            {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"valid email address",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else 
            {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Invalid email address", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });
```

tried these two patterns but i am getting message as Invalid email addressfor any correct email id i enter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is fine. You just need to read your email address inside the click listener as

```
btnchk.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        String email = edt.getText().toString().trim();
        if (email.matches(emailPattern))
        {
```

The issue is that you're reading your `edt` textbox when it's *empty* and hence the *regex* test fails.

Answer (score 1):

I think that @Ravi has spotted the immediate cause of your problem.  You are not validating the correct string.

However, your regex is also wrong, as it excludes numerous email addresses that are in fact valid.  For example:

- the local part can be a quoted string
- the local part can include all sorts of non-alphanumeric characters
- the domain part could have one component, or more than two components
- the domain part can be an IP address, and
- the local and domain parts can include non-ASCII characters.

Reference:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address
- http://davidcel.is/blog/2012/09/06/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    if(isEditTextContainEmail(edtEmailAddress))
    {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"valid email address",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    else 
    {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Invalid email address", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Using this method:

```
public static boolean isEditTextContainEmail(EditText argEditText) {

    try {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[_A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(argEditText.getText());
        return matcher.matches();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this reg-ex:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z]+\.[a-z]+
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this is better solution for chek email validation try this..

```
public final static boolean isValidEmail(CharSequence yourEmail) {
    if (yourEmail== null) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(yourEmail).matches();
    }
}
```

i hope to work for your case :)